# Creating IsHoliday feature in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to create an IsHoliday feature in my pd.dataframe,having datetime as index, based on a csv file whice includes the holidays in one year. Having little experience with pandas i can think of an iterative approach by comparing the values of the two dataframes 
To be more specific :

```
for i in range(0,len(Holidays)-1):
 for j in range(0,len(df)-1):
    if (Holidays.loc[i,'month']==df.loc[j,'month'] and 
      Holidays.loc[i,'day']==df.loc[j,'day'] ):
        df.loc[j,'Isholiday']=1

    else: 
        df.loc[j,'Isholiday']=0
```

My question is how can this be implemented the pandas way avoiding all the proccesing time?

Comment: Pandas has built-in functions for doing this kind of thing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for that:

```
df['IsHoliday'] = np.where(df.index.isin(Holidays),True,False)
```

Comment: Did it help @maxthunder ? Share the dataframes so I can give you a more precise answer otherwise

Comment: Glad it did :) please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer in that case